# Ensuring thread safety with ASP.Net cache - a tale of two strategies

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have code that is not currently thread safe:

```
public byte[] GetImageByteArray(string filepath, string contentType, RImgOptions options)
{               
    //Our unique cache keys will be composed of both the image's filepath and the requested width
    var cacheKey = filepath + options.Width.ToString();
    var image = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];

    //If there is nothing in the cache, we need to generate the image, insert it into the cache, and return it
    if (image == null)
    {
        RImgGenerator generator = new RImgGenerator();
        byte[] bytes = generator.GenerateImage(filepath, contentType, options);
        CacheItem(cacheKey, bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
    //Image already exists in cache, serve it up!
    else
    {
        return (byte[])image;
    }
}
```

My `CacheItem()` method checks to see if its max cache size has been reached, and if it has, it will start removing cached items:

```
//If the cache exceeds its max allotment, we will remove items until it falls below the max
while ((int)cache[CACHE_SIZE] > RImgConfig.Settings.Profile.CacheSize * 1000 * 1000)
{
    var entries = (Dictionary<string, DateTime>)cache[CACHE_ENTRIES];
    var earliestCacheItem = entries.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == entries.Min(d => d.Value));
    int length = ((byte[])cache[earliestCacheItem.Key]).Length;
    cache.Remove(earliestCacheItem.Key);
    cache[CACHE_SIZE] = (int)cache[CACHE_SIZE] - length;
}
```

Since one thread could remove an item from the cache as another thread is referencing it, I can think of two options:

**Option 1: A lock**

```
lock (myLockObject)
{
    if(image == null){ **SNIP** }
}
```

**Option 2: Assign a shallow copy to a local variable**

```
var image = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey].MemberwiseClone() : null;
```

Both of these options have overhead. The first forces threads to enter that code block one at a time. The second necessitates creating a new object in memory which could be of non-trivial size.

Are there any other strategies I could employ here?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this code.  Removing the item from the cache does not dispose of it, as far as I can tell.  So removing it from the cache only removes the reference.  The object referencing it should be unaffected, unless you explicitly dispose of it.  The Cache itself is thread safe, so you don't have to worry about the object being removed while you are looking it up.

Comment: You also know you can set a maximum size for the cache in your web.config?  And when this size is reached, asp.net will itself start pruning the cache?  I'm not sure why you feel the need to do this yourself...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I believe what you are saying has truth to it, the local `image` variable will hold a reference making the object the cache is pointing to ineligible for garbage collection. I was looking at an example where a local variable wasn't used (but probably should be), and instead re-queried the cache in in two separate operations, so a lock was employed. At any rate, thanks for making it clear my two unappetizing options are not required.

Comment: And as for caching options in the web.config, yes, I am aware, but to my knowledge it doesn't provide you control as to *how* you prune your cache. I'll be employing a few different strategies so I had to roll my own solution.

Comment: Built in cache scavenging works in two ways, Least recently used (which your method seems to be doing, so you're just duplicating the built-in functionality, but more likely in a less efficient manner) and Priority.  If you want to do your own algorithm, you can mark items with different priorities and still let built-in scavenger do the work for you.  See CachePriority class.  It seems rather pointless to query the cache twice, I would suggest addressing that algorithm rather than looking for a problem that doesn't really exist.

Comment: The simple fact is, cache logic is *hard*.  And it's largely a solved problem.  You should, as much as possible, rely on existing functionality in the framework because it's well written and debugged and used by millions of users.  Writing your own will largely just introduce more bugs, and less efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide pure consistency of your cache solution you should lock your resource while slowing down the application.

In general, you should try to provide caching strategy, based on your application logic.

- Check sliding window caching: while item which is older when some
  time span - will reduce locking of different threads - good when you
  have large spread of different cached items which not for sure will
  be used again.
- Consider using least frequently used strategy: the item that is least used
  should be removed while reached max cache size - best serves while
  you have multiple client hitting frequently same part of cached
  content.

Just check which one more suites better your type of BL and use it. It will not remove the locking issue at all, but right choice will significantly remove racing conditions.

In order to reduce shared resource between different threads, use read and write locks on each item and not on entire collection. This will boost your performance as well.

Another point of consideration that should be kept in mind - what if content of image with the same path is changed physically on the disk (different image was saved with the same name) while having this image already cached there is a chance of mistakenly provide not relevant data.

Hope it helped.